# Hiding an element by ID when in local storage once clicked not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this script to refresh the page after a button has been clicked and to hide that button once the ID (the shortcode) has been stored locally and to show a second element underneath:

```
function myVote(shortcode) {
  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
  // Set product in local storage 
    localStorage.setItem(shortcode, "true");
   // Refresh page after 3000 milliseconds
   setTimeout(function() { location.reload(true); }, 3000);
  });
};
</script>

<script>
for(let i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(localStorage.key(i)).style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

The button has the following value: `onClick="myVote('shortcode');"`

The "shortcode" values are dynamic, each element has it's own.

I have built an upvoting system and the above means that once a vote has been placed they won't be able to vote for it again (unless they use another device or clear storage), the vote button is hidden and the "voted" button is now displayed. But for some reason, it's not working as it should and I'm struggling to figure it out. Check it out at https://www.carryr.com/vote.

At first, I thought I didn't configure the z-index for both of the element but they seem fine to me; the element underneath has a z-index of 11 and the one on top 100.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing many things in local storage which are not element ids.
So there will be an error when you try to access style property on an element that does not exist. Hence this code doesn't work.

Suggestion:
1.

```
const elm = document.getElementById(localstorage.key(i));
if (elm) {
  elm.style.display="none"
}
```

2.It's better if you store the voted ids in a separate object and store it in storage. and read that object on load and style based on that.

```
// setting to storage
let voted = localStorage.getItem('voted');
if (!voted) {
voted = {};
} else {
voted = JSON.parse(voted);
}
voted.shortCode = true;

localStorage.setItem('voted',JSON.stringify(voted));

// reading from storage
voted = localStorage.getItem('voted');
if (!voted) {
voted = {}
} else {
voted = JSON.parse(voted);
}
Object.keys(voted).forEach(key => document.getElementById(key).style.display = 'none';
```

3. The above methods only store data in localstorage. so if user clears cache, opens a incognito window, opens in another system he won't be able to see the votes. better persist the state in a DB if possible

Comment: I think the second option may be better, how would I go about doing this? (I'm a bit of a nubie)

Comment: Looks like we're getting there, it's not the "voted IDs" I need to display as none, it's the myVote(shortcode). Also, how would I be able to keep the setTimeout in there too? Essentially, I need the shortcode ID to be registered as true when the element is clicked, the timeout to happen to refresh the vote count (based on the services I'm using) and when the page is refreshed, I will need to look into storage for the elements that have been clicked so that they can be hidden to display an element underneath

Comment: just replace the above read and write snippets in your code

Answer (score 0):

The SetTimeout may be the reason as after clicking on the said button, tahe page gets reload and localstorage value become null. Hence, the page throws document.getElementById(...) is null exception.

Please remove Timeout and retry the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the SetTimeout to refresh the vote count... not unless there's a better way of managing it?

Comment: Ajax is the best way to do the same without reloading entire page and server traffic would also be reduced.